# Differences in consuming items in Nethack vs Slashem

Tags: nethack, slashem

I have started playing Slash'em extended, and do not know how to quaff potions or eat corpses from the floor without picking them up first. Normally, on alt.nethack.org, I would just hit q and it would pop up a "Quaff from fountain?" command, but that is not the case on Slash'em extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLASH'EM changes the "use item on ground" command to be the item "." in the regular prompt instead of being a separate prompt. You should see "." included in the items you can eat/drink if you're standing on the appropriate square. Select that to eat the item/drink from the fountain.